# Complement of $S^1$ in a simply connected oriented surface

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, compactness, surfaces, fundamental-groups

The complement of any $C^1$-embedded circle $S^1$ in an oriented simply connected surface of regularity $C^1$ has exactly two components by the theorem of Stokes. Now it seems evident to me that there is always one component which is both simply connected and relatively compact.

I do not see the cause although it seems "obvious" to me that one of them has to be covered by the image of any zero homotopy of the embedded circle.

Are there any good references which would permit a hint?

Comment: The key word is "Schoenfiles theorem", which says that not only is one component both simply connected and relatively compact, but in fact one of the components has closure homeomorphic to $D^2$ with the component itself corresponding to the interior of $D^2$.

Comment: Thank you. Is it appropriate to prove what I mentioned above _without_ assuming the classification of oriented simply connected $C^1$-surfaces? Which indeed would be confortable thanks to the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: Yes, that is appropriate. I believe that in the $C^1$ category, the $C^1$ Jordan-Schoenflies theorem is a prerequisite for the $C^1$ classification of surfaces. I *know* that this is so in the topological category.

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose one of the two components to be relatively compact, then it is also simply connected by Poincare duality between De Rham cohomology with and without compact supports (cf. Bott-Tu) and between De Rham cohomology and simplicial homology alias abelianised fundamental group.

At least in the proof of Riemann uniformisation theorem, relative compactness of one component of complements of occuring cercles can be achieved by means of an appropriate exhaustion function.